# Add class with :hover using CSS

Tags: html, css, styles

I first say I cant use javascript.

So my question is this: I want to be able to add a class to an element when mouse hovers it. I cant add the styles into the :hover cause they are many.

I use animate.css in my page. There are tons of effects, and for example I want to add the class "fadeInUp" when the user hovers an element in the page. Doing this with javascript would be trivial, but how about css? Is it possible to add a class when :hover?

Comment: You can't add a class with CSS. Depending what you intend to do you may be able to mimic the effect of adding a class. Please create an example.

Comment: Of course, you could use javascript to add/remove a class on mouseIn or mouseOut events.

Comment: I don't see why you can't just add another custom class yourself and on :hover give it the styles of the class you want.  If there are many styles, it'd still be the same as a class with many styles.

Comment: You could do so using jQuery.  Override the OnMouseOver & OnMouseOut events...and apply/remove your class accordingly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very simply, **No.**

Assuming I got you correctly, you want to **ADD** a class.
That is not possible.

If you wanted to however, you could copy the css code that you need over from the `animate.css` file mentioned, and apply that on the pseudo-class `:hover`.

There isn't a way for CSS to manipulate with the classes and IDs directly, other than with its pseudo-classes.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Is that for sure? I've cases of Chrome extensions where I disabled the javascript (both the in the main page and the extension page), and then I hovered over an element, and a class was added to the element.